# Get an hash combining array and constants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have this array

```
Animals = ['sad cat','happy dog','vegetarian fish','hungry shark']
```

and these constants

```
SAD_CATS = {somekey : somevalue, otherkey : othervalue}
HAPPY_DOGS = {somekey : somevalue, otherkey : othervalue}
VEGETARIAN_FISH = {somekey : somevalue, otherkey : othervalue}
HUNGRY_SHARKS = {somekey : somevalue, otherkey : othervalue}
```

Which is the best way to get this?

```
RESULT = {'sad-cat' => SAD_CATS ,'happy-dog' => HAPPY_DOGS ,'vegetarian-fish' => VEGETARIAN_FISHES ,'hungry-shark' => HUNGRY_SHARKES }
```

Notice that the constas are the pluralizes and upcased values of the arrays.

I tried with

```
RESULT = Animals.map(:&parameterize).map(:&upcase)
```

but it doesn't work as I expect

**EDITED**

Because *FISHES* isn't english

Comment: You've made some substantive clarifications in your comments (e.g. willingness to rely on Rails functionality, willingness to change your constant spelling to match Rails conventions). I suggest you edit your question to make that clear, preferable with a supplemental note given the effort already put into answers.

Comment: Note also that you said that the constants were "pluralized and upcased values of the arrays". I assume you meant "of the _elements in the array_", but in any event, this ignores that you've changed the spaces to underbars in the constants and changed the spaces to dashes in the keys of the sample hash output.

Comment: :-) I deleted my comment about downvotes. It would still help if you clarified "Notice that the constas are the pluralizes and upcased values of the arrays." with respect to dashes in the keys, particularly since three of your four answers don't produce the value of `RESULT` that you included in your question.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I don't have enough reputation to downwote anything... :(

Comment: My situation is the following. I have an array with some values coming from the DB. (I receive a string with comma separated values and I transform it in an array)
I use that array to do a lot of things, for example to draw some tabs, or titles and so on... 

In a place I need the route related to the values of the array, (`sad-cat` for `sad cat` for example). 
In another place I receive that route and I need to point to the related constant (in this example SAD_CATS).

Actually I hardcoded my _RESULT_ hash but it will be easyer for me if I could generate it dinamically from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're ok with a Rails-based solution and are willing to change your "fish" and "shark" pluralization to match the Rails default, you can use the following. I've modified the value of the constants to make validation of the output more readable.

```
Animals = ['sad cat','happy dog','vegetarian fish','hungry shark']

SAD_CATS = :cat_constant
HAPPY_DOGS = :dog_constant
VEGETARIAN_FISH = :fish_constant
HUNGRY_SHARKS = :shark_constant

Hash[Animals.map do |a|
  [a.gsub(' ','-'), a.gsub(' ','_').pluralize.upcase.constantize]
  end]

 => {"sad-cat"=>:cat_constant, "happy-dog"=>:dog_constant, "vegetarian-fish"=>:fish_constant, "hungry-shark"=>:shark_constant}
```

If you want a Ruby only solution, you can use this. Of course, you can avoid the monkey patching of `String` if you'd prefer.

```
Animals = ['sad cat','happy dog','vegetarian fish','hungry shark']

SAD_CATS = :cat_constant
HAPPY_DOGS = :dog_constant
VEGETARIAN_FISHES = :fish_constant
HUNGRY_SHARKES = :shark_constant

class String
  PLURALIZATION_EXCEPTIONS = {shark: 'es', fish: 'es'}
  def pluralize
    self+(PLURALIZATION_EXCEPTIONS[self.split(' ')[-1].to_sym] || 's')
  end
end

Hash[Animals.map do |a|
  [a.gsub(' ','-'), self.class.const_get(a.pluralize.gsub(' ','_').upcase)]
  end]

 => {"sad-cat"=>:cat_constant, "happy-dog"=>:dog_constant, "vegetarian-fish"=>:fish_constant, "hungry-shark"=>:shark_constant}
```

Comment: This is exactly was I looking for. Although I have done a mistake in the question. `Animals` stays in the model but the `RESULT` (and the others hashes) should stay in the decorator...

Answer (score -1):

I'd go with:

```
animals.each_with_object({}) do |a, h| 
 h[a.parameterize] = a.pluralize.upcase.tr(' ', '_').constantize
end
```

Note: "fish" in plural is the same

Docs:

http://apidock.com/rails/String/parameterize

http://apidock.com/rails/String/pluralize

http://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize

Comment: Where is `parameterize` defined?

Comment: @Bartosz you can add that link into your post, to increase its understandability.

Comment: Just did. Thanks for the downvotes despite of this being exactly what the author wanted.

Comment: Actually, it's not really what the OP wanted. :-) Have you compared your hash keys to those the op provided?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, Bartosz Do I smell ingratitude? There are some good answers here. What's going on?

Comment: I assumed typos in the key names as he stated later that the keys are the pluralized version.

Comment: @mjnissim I'm not sure. :-) I thought the lack of handling of the `-` in the keys might explain the downvotes, but I got one too and I handled it. I also suspect it's not the OP, but who knows.

Comment: @Bartosz Oh, I didn't see where he said the keys were pluralized. Where was that?

Comment: From the question: `Notice that the constants are the pluralized and upcased values of the arrays.`

Answer (score -1):

The elements in your array denote singular entities, while your constants (ignoring the case) denote plural entities ('sad cat' vs 'SAD_CATS' or 'vegetarian fish' vs 'VEGETARIAN_FISHES').

I doubt if such auto-pluralisation is possible in Ruby or Rails.

However, if your constants were singular, as follows:

```
SAD_CAT         = {somekey: somevalue, otherkey: othervalue}
HAPPY_DOG       = {somekey: somevalue, otherkey: othervalue}
VEGETARIAN_FISH = {somekey: somevalue, otherkey: othervalue}
HUNGRY_SHARK    = {somekey: somevalue, otherkey: othervalue}
```

then, the following would give you the required result:

```
RESULT = Hash[Animals.collect { |x| [x, eval(x.gsub(' ', '_').upcase)] }]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Rails _does_ support pluralization via ActiveSupport

Comment: Yeah, saw your answer and I appreciate it, especially not using the 'eval'. But still I would prefer renaming my constants than overriding such methods since the code would look simple and easy to maintain.

Answer (score -1):

Here's your solution:

```
RESULT = Animals.inject({}) do |h, animal|
  h.merge animal.parameterize => animal.pluralize.underscore.gsub(' ', '_').upcase.constantize
end
```

Only please note that plural for shark is not "sharkes", but "sharks", and plural for "fish" is... "fish".

Comment: I'm quite sure it doesn't now. `'fish'.pluralize => "fish"`

Comment: Hmm. So it does. Thought I confirmed that ... Deleting comment.